# Tsv table has some dates being expressed with pound-sign

Tags: excel, date, export-to-excel

For an internal database I'm building, I have a sqlite database, and I want to use python to export it into a tsv file.  The current problem is that some of my dates are being replaced with '######', and when double-clicked, become actual dates.  Could somebody please help?

Note:  Nothing else changes, including type (they're both date, as excel 2007 indicates).
[image: Before Clicking]
[image: After Clicking]

If anyone wants to see the python source code, please comment, but I don't currently see a reason as to why I need to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean the `####` appear in Excel?

This is a common issue: when Excel cannot display the whole value of a cell, it displays `###` until it can show the whole value. This is **display** only.

[STFW](http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=why+excel+display+%23%23%23) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks!  That was a great help.  This means my tsv file is valid, right?

Comment: Yes it is. Only, the display was misleading you :)